# Считывание строки с новой строки

Tags: c++

Как можно считать в первой строке число, а во второй строку?
getline видимо начинает считывать с символа \n.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N;
    string s;
    cin >> N;
    getline(cin, s);
    cout << N << endl;
    cout << s << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После чтения `N` сбросьте буфер ввода:

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```